# Create Object type from Array type where keys are values of property in each object from array

Tags: typescript

Given a type that is an array of objects, how do I create a new type that is an object, where the keys are values of a specific property in the array objects, and the values of the object are the type of one of the object generics.

With JS code, it would look like this:

```
const obj = arr.reduce((acc, element) => ({
  ...acc,
  [element.name]: element.bar
}))
```

So far I have this:

```
type ArrayToObject<Arr extends Array<CustomType<any>> = []> = {
  [K in keyof Arr]: ExtractCustomTypeGeneric<Arr[K]>
}

type ExtractCustomTypeGeneric<A> = A extends CustomType<infer T> ? T : never;

type CustomType<T> = {
  name: string,
  foo: number,
  bar: T
}
```

This gives me an array object (since `K in keyof Arr` are index numbers), whereas I would want the property keys to be `name`. Unfortunately something like `[Arr[K]['name'] for K in keyof Arr]` isn't something that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a union of all the keys in the array using `Arr[number]['name']`, then you can use `Extract` to extract from the union of all possible elements in the array (`Arr[number]`) just the items that have the currently mapped `name`:

```
type ArrayToObject<Arr extends Array<CustomType<any>> = []> = {
  [K in Arr[number]['name']]: ExtractCustomTypeGeneric<Extract<Arr[number], { name: K }>>
}

type ExtractCustomTypeGeneric<A> = A extends CustomType<infer T> ? T : never;

type CustomType<T, K = string> = {
  name: K,
  bar: T
}

function createItems<T extends Array<CustomType<any, K>>, K extends string>(...a: T) : T{
    return a;
}

let a = createItems({ name: "A", bar: ""}, { name: "B", bar: 0})

type R = ArrayToObject<typeof a>
//Same as 
type R = {
    A: string;
    B: number;
}
```

[Play](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAKgewPICMBWEDGwAPPHFBAB7AQB2AJgM6wLJEDCArg8GgLYrgIRRDRAA+MVAC8UANoBdSTIDeAKChyA0lACWNZnFk0OvLBDjzZAchqJeEK-PkAuKAFEqSQp258BkAHFacx18Ig9gL2JSIxMzCwAaKGUoW3tXbQBfCVVM1VVQSHdPRG8uHn5BIJoQsJglWHIqWkYoHwr-IT0AM3MoFEkAfn6oVxqAN3MAbnzC6Ha-QSIUJO0Zbjg9AHMGtQ00iAyE9SgsRDhXFFz87o4aQh00fXw4CERqAElqXgZlpup6ExSKwFpVIMJRKsJKt-i0mBttmIABQAOjRiEuAEpRv09hooK9gBw4PpEDM8qoADYQYBQRDSKAvN6fb4MJEpA6uABEMC5STOFygXK5mSSHLshyFACE+adzq4AAyZTGzQRQABKDOBqEwuAIxDmaG6dLEQA)

Comment: Wow. :-) Suppose I wanted to do this without a function? E.g., my starting point was `const fields = [{ name: "A", bar: ""}, { name: "B", bar: 0}];` and I wanted to get the type `{ A: string; B: number; }`? I tried but failed to make it work without the function, embarrassingly. :-) (Context: To use Amazon's RDS efficiently I need to have a `fields`-like object so I know what property name to use to get the value of a column. So I'd prefer not to have to maintain both runtime and compile-time type information for my business objects...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `as const` on the constant initalizer will almost get you there, but that will preserve the actual literal type instead of widening to `string` or `number` (`{  A: "";   B: 0;}`). Functions are still the best way to have fine grained control over inference.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, that was indeed the stumbling block for me, that I ended up with `""` and `0` rather than `string` and `number`. That's too bad. I wanted to avoid having to pass *both* a type and a schema object to the function. But I'm stuck with either `let users: User[] = executeQuery("select ...", UserSchema);` or `let users = executeQuery<User>("select ...", UserSchema);`. I guess since the latter doesn't require the type gymnastics above, I'll use it. So close! :-)